# Does the pattern of Backbone.js break the MVC of CI

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter, backbone.js

I am using Backbone.js together with CI.
So there is a MVC frontend and backend.

All Backbone.js needs is a JSON response back from the server, then it'll take care of the display, and handle the separation of response into different models.
Therefore, I echoed the resp back in a CI model. So my workflow is:

CI Controller->CI Model (echo)->Backbone.js

Is this how you would mix Backbone.js and CI? Or am i doing it wrong?

To implement REST, I did this:

```
            $this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD');
```

and then a switch statement follows to route the to right function in the controller, and then send to the model, which echo back json.

Comment: If i am not wrong than true mvc workflow must be `model > controller > view > backbone`

Comment: Are you using the rest server plugin for CI?

Comment: @ant_Ti - I can pass the data to a view. But since Backbone.js is doing the rendering of display, the echo in the view will just pass through the data.

Comment: @Pat - No, I'm not. Please see update.

Comment: @Pat - But REST has to do with how you receive data, not the subsequent MVC process

Answer (score 1):

CI as it stands may not be the best match for a purely backbone based UI.  If you work up your CI routes to be "RESTful" in nature, and are purely returning JSON, then you are probably OK, but you may be better off standing up a full blown REST sever in leu of or in addition to your CI instance.

Comment: Why does setting up REST has to do with my views? I thought REST has to do with how you receive data, and the view is when you send back data

Comment: Views are only how you render the data you have, not how  you send it back.  All communication through the server should be done through backbone models, if you can.  Backbone models were written to work with a RESTful interface.  It is because of this, that I recommended standing up your own REST interface..

Comment: Does it count as RESTful if i simply echo back JSON, and when .fetch() is called, parse() is also called to parse the JSON

Comment: Yes, but that isn't really what RESTful means.  REST is a methodology, more so than a technology.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST

Comment: I agree. i believe the rest of my code is pretty RESTful. Do you have any suggestion as to what I should use instead of echo back the response (which is JSON encoded)